# Azure powershell command fails from c# application

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to invoke Azure Powershell commands from my c# app( running with windows auth)
The  Azure powershell sdk was installed on the Windows 2012 R2 box for 'User1' who is also the admin of the network as well as box.
Code used:

```
string psFile= @"C:\AVC\Vmstatus.ps1 -VmName testvm";
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(psFile);
            pipeline.InvokeAsync();
            WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[2];
            handles[0] = pipeline.Output.WaitHandle;
            handles[1] = pipeline.Error.WaitHandle;

            while (pipeline.PipelineStateInfo.State == PipelineState.Running)
            {
                switch (WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles))
                {
                    case 0: a = pipeline.Output.Read();
                        vm.ip = ((dynamic)a).IpAddress;
                        vm.vmStatus = ((dynamic)a).PowerState;
                        vm.vmName = ((dynamic)a).name;


                        break;
                    case 1: object b = pipeline.Error.Read();
                        throw new CryptographicException(b.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Scenario's

1. Code run from VS 2013 while logged in as User1 - Works
2. Code run from Vs 2013 while logged in as User2 - works
3. Code run from iis as User1 -Works
4. Wierdest of all=> Code run from IIS as user2 While USer1 is logged into the box -Works
5. Code run from IIS as User 2 - DOES NOT WORK
6. Running from plain powershell as User 2- Works
7. Running from Azure powershell cmd as user 2-works

I am using VS to debug the IIS applicationa nd the exception received is

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.

FullyQualifiedErrorId = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.ImportAzurePublishSettingsCommand"
```

Digging into the issue :
1) The certificate is installed for user1 and user 2